# Remove setTimeout from Meteor.method

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, node-fibers

Gist: https://gist.github.com/FA-ViPer/39d6529edf8be6d376a9#file-gistfile1-txt

I'm not sure how to remove the setTimeout function from the below code and still have my tracks variable available to insert into the collection "Carousel".

```
asyncJob: function(id) {
  Future = Meteor.npmRequire('fibers/future');
  Fiber =  Meteor.npmRequire('fibers');
  // Set up a future
  var fut = new Future();
  var tracks;

  //ueses a promise to get the tracks
  musicApi.getMySavedTracks()
    .then(function(data) {
      tracks = data.items;
      console.log(Carousel.findOne({}));
    }, function(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return "failure";
    });
  // I do not know how to rework the portion below to not have the setTimeout
  //the end goal is to replace the console.log with Carousel.insert({track});
  setTimeout(function() {
    Fiber(function() {console.log(Carousel.findOne({}), tracks.length);}).run();
    // Return the results
    fut['return'](tracks);
  }, 3 * 1000);

  // Wait for async to finish before returning the result
  return fut.wait();
}
```

Comment: Put the code inside the asynchronous callback...aka Logic needs to be in the `then`

Comment: works perfectly. I'm still uncertain about the differences between a promise and a ?callback?/async function?